# Open fragment with expansion animation from a View

Tags: java, android, animation

How can we open a fragment when a Card is clicked, expanding that card into a fullscreen fragment? The perfect example is Google Calendar's animation, when an event is clicked.

Right now I'm opening the fragment with a simple slide animation:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
NewReminderFragment frag = new NewReminderFragment();
fragmentManager.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_back_in, R.anim.slide_back_out)
        .replace(R.id.mainContainer, frag)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

I've looked into a lot of libraries and I coudn't find any for this.